# Object does not support this property or method for function defined on jQuery prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an IE shim for various tidbits of functionality that sane browsers provide out of the box (unfortunately, I am in a position where IE7 support is mandatory).

I've got the following method definition defined on the jQuery prototype:

```
    $.fn.textWidth = function(){
         //some logic in here
    }

    shimSelect = function(selector){
       $(selector).on('focus', function(){
            $(this).each(function(index, element){
                   if(element.textWidth() > element.width){
                        //more logic
                   }
            }
        }
     }

     if (!$.support.leadingWhitespace) {
         $(function() {
             shimSelect("");
         });
     }
```

By judiciously adding various console.logs, I have established that directly before the call to textWidth the element is an HTMLElement(specifically and HTMLSelectElement) in my case.

However, it refuses to call textWidth(), failing with `Object does not support this property or method` in IE and with

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLSelectElement> has no method 'textWidth' shim.js:104
        (anonymous function) togo_ie_shim.js:104
        jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:612
        jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js:242
        (anonymous function) togo_ie_shim.js:103
        jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3064
        elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

on Chrome

My questions are, what is wrong with my code? Why is it failing? And how can I implement a similiar shim correctly?

Comment: `<HTMLSelectElement> has no method 'textWidth'`

Comment: If I read the jQuery [documentation for .each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) correctly, `element` is the actual DOM element, which doesn't have a `textWidth` property. Try `$(element).textWidth()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function does not give you the jquery object as argument, it's a DOM object.

```
jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )
```

You have extended the jquery object, hence, **element** has no function textWidth defined on it.

Try using : `$(element)` instead.